# MvvmLight, PCL and System.Runtime

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, portable-class-library

I have a VS2012 solution that contains a Portable Class Library that targets .NET 4.5, Silverlight 5 and Windows Phone 8. This PCL also references MvvmLight (PCL). I then have a Windows Phone 8 project which references this PCL. For the WP8 project I loaded the MvvmLight (PCL) NuGet Package which loaded MvvmLight, MvvmLight.Extras as well as MvvmLight.Platform.WP8.

But, when I compile the WP8 project it complains that I have an indirect reference to "System.Runtime, Version=2.5.19.0". This is true because the PCL project exposes a view model that has the ViewModelBase class as a base class, which in turn requires the System.Runtime.dll.

If I reference the platform specific versions of MvvmLight in the WP8 project, i.e. the MvvmLight NuGet package, then I also have to reference the Microsoft.Bcl.Build package and when I do that I get load more errors referring to Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.

I have tried adding the System.Runtime.dll from the Microsoft.Bcl directory, but it does not solve the problem.

Is there something I'm missing or not tried?!?

Answer (score 1):

This is an [issue](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3072) where NuGet is adding binding redirects when it shouldn't.  Deleting the binding redirects for System.Runtime (and System.Threading.Tasks if it exists) from the app.config in your WP8 project should fix this.